# Check for new files in multiple folders, Report that new file does or does not exist

Tags: powershell-2.0

I am a 2 day newbie with Powershell 2.0. I have searched and come this far, but I am stuck with what to do further. Please bear with me I tried to search!

Task: Create a PS file that searches subfolders in a folder. Each folder contains a site backup file. I need to know if a new file was created and report if the file was or was not created.

The PS file needs to do the following:

1. Check a folder
2. If new files exists say "ok" else "not OK"
3. Do this for 28 folders creating 28 statements
4. dump write-output to common function (email)
5. use data from email in the body of an email.

Problems:

1. One search goes OK, when I add another I get false answers. I suspect this has something to do with using the same variables over and over.
2. I'm still a bit lost on how to get a carriage return to work in the body of the email. Everything goes on one continuous line.

I am suspecting I have unneeded statements in my creation. The file is bits and pieces of answers I have found here. I am having trouble putting it together properly for my needs. Guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
#Site #1
$fullPath = "\\10.10.1.5\working\$folder"
$folder1= "test1"
$numdays = 0
$numhours = 10
$nummins = 0
$site = "site 1"

function Verify1($path, $days, $hours, $mins)
{$files = @(get-childitem $path -include *.* -recurse | where {($_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days).AddHours(-$hours).AddMinutes(-$mins)) -and ($_.psIsContainer -eq $false)})
if ($files -ne $NULL)
{$file = $files
write-host ("The backup File for " + $site + " was backed up successfully!!")}
else {write-host ("The backup File for " + $site + " WAS NOT backed up successfully!!")}}
Verify1 $fullPath $numdays $numhours $nummins

#Site #2
$fullPath = "\\10.10.1.5\working\$folder"
$folder2= "test2"
$numdays2 = 0
$numhours2 = 10
$nummins2 = 0
$site = "site 2"

function Verify2($path, $days, $hours, $mins)
{$files = @(get-childitem $path -include *.* -recurse | where {($_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days).AddHours(-$hours).AddMinutes(-$mins)) -and ($_.psIsContainer -eq $false)})
if ($files -ne $NULL)
{$file = $files
write-host ("The backup File for " + $site + " was backed up successfully!!")}
else {write-host ("The backup File for " + $site + " WAS NOT backed up successfully!!")}}
Verify2 $fullPath2 $numdays $numhours $nummins

function email {
process { Write-Host $_ }
}

#verify1 | email
#verify2 | email

$date = (Get-Date).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')

$EmailFrom = "email@gmail.com"
$EmailTo = "email@gmail.com" 
$Subject = ("Daily Database Report for " + $date)
[string]$body = ""



foreach ($email in $emails) {$body = $body + "`r`n"}



$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com" 
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password"); 
$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1

Issue looks likes coming from the variables carrying the same name.
If you look at site 2, it has full path looking at $folder which does not exist in either config blocks.

Something like

```
#Config Block
#Folders
$folder1= "test1"
$folder2= "test2"

#Remote Paths
$fullPath1 = "\\10.10.1.5\working\$folder1"
$fullPath2 = "\\10.10.1.5\working\$folder2"

#Site Names
$site1 = "Site 1"
$site2 = "Site 2"

#Time Difference
$numdays = 0
$numhours = 10
$nummins = 0

#Function
function VerifySite($Path, $Site, $Days, $Hours, $Mins)
{$files = @(get-childitem $path -include *.* -recurse | where {($_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days).AddHours(-$hours).AddMinutes(-$mins)) -and ($_.psIsContainer -eq $false)})
if ($files -ne $NULL)
{$file = $files
write-host ("The backup File for " + $site + " was backed up successfully!!")}
else {write-host ("The backup File for " + $site + " WAS NOT backed up successfully!!")}}


VerifySite $fullPath1 $Site1 $numdays $numhours $nummins
VerifySite $fullPath2 $Site2 $numdays $numhours $nummins
```

might archive the desired results. Cleaned up the configuration so it can be read easier and removed the second verify function as it wasn't required.

Had a chance to revist this and look at problem 2.

Problem 2.

Email body.

I reworked it a bit to produce a log file. I then built the email body from the logfile and finally removed the logfile

```
#Config Block
#Folders
$folder1= "test1"
$folder2= "test2"
$folder3= "test3"
$folder4= "test4"
$folder5= "test5"

#Remote Paths
$fullPath1 = "\\10.10.1.5\working\$folder1"
$fullPath2 = "\\10.10.1.5\working\$folder2"
$fullPath3 = "\\10.10.1.5\working\$folder3"
$fullPath4 = "\\10.10.1.5\working\$folder4"
$fullPath5 = "\\10.10.1.5\working\$folder5"

#Site Names
$site1 = "Site 1"
$site2 = "Site 2"
$site3 = "Site 3"
$site4 = "Site 4"
$site5 = "Site 5"

#Time Difference
#Days
$numdays1 = 0
$numdays2 = 1
#Hours
$numhours1 = 10
$numhours2 = 15
#Mins
$nummins1 = 0
$nummins2 = 0

#Dates
$date = (Get-Date).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')
$Logdate = (Get-Date).ToString('MMddyyyy')

#logs
$logFile = "D:\Log_$Logdate.txt"

#Email
$EmailFrom = "email@gmail.com"
$EmailTo = "email@gmail.com" 
$Subject = ("Daily Database Report for " + $date)

#Function
function VerifySite($Path, $Site, $Days, $Hours, $Mins)
{$files = @(get-childitem $path -include *.* -recurse | where {($_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days).AddHours(-$hours).AddMinutes(-$mins)) -and ($_.psIsContainer -eq $false)})
if ($files -ne $NULL)
{$file = $files
write-output ($Date + " The backup File for " + $site + " was backed up successfully!!") | Out-File $logFile -Append }
else {write-output ($Date + " The backup File for " + $site + " WAS NOT backed up successfully!!") | Out-File $logFile -Append}}

#Commands 
VerifySite $fullPath1 $Site1 $numdays2 $numhours1 $nummins1
VerifySite $fullPath2 $Site2 $numdays1 $numhours2 $nummins2
VerifySite $fullPath3 $Site3 $numdays1 $numhours1 $nummins1
VerifySite $fullPath4 $Site4 $numdays1 $numhours2 $nummins1
VerifySite $fullPath5 $Site5 $numdays2 $numhours1 $nummins2

[string]$body = ""
$logs = Get-Content $logFile

foreach ($log in $logs )
{
    $body = $body + $log + "`r`n"
}

$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com" 
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password"); 
$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)

#Cleanup if required.
remove-item $logFile
```

You should get $body returning something like

```
11/02/2015 The backup File for Site 1 WAS NOT backed up successfully!!
11/02/2015 The backup File for Site 2 was backed up successfully!!
```

Also reworked the variables a bit to show how it can be expanded.